# How can i save objects to core data without leaks

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, core-data, memory-leaks

I have almost the same core data stack #2 : http://floriankugler.com/2013/04/29/concurrent-core-data-stack-performance-shootout/ . (mine is singleton)
After i save on worker moc (last moc) i get leaks (leaks app_name in terminal). 
This is my save function:

```
func saveToLast(moc: NSManagedObjectContext?) throws{
        if let moc = moc {
            moc.performAndWait({ _ in
                if moc.hasChanges {
                    do {
                        try moc.save()
                        if let parentMoc = moc.parent {
                            try self.saveToLast(moc: parentMoc)
                        }
                    }
                    catch {

                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

if i keep performAndWait i know sooner or later i will create a deadlock and if i put perform theres no guarantee the background thread saves on worker before main thread (in order).
Can anyone explain me how can i save with serial queues or any good alternative to what i wrote?

Comment: Which iOS / Swift version are you using to test? And are you using the simulator or a real device?

Comment: Ios 10 swift 3 simulator

Comment: I'm also getting lots of (minor) leaks using iOS 10 and Swift 3 together. I've filed several bug reports already and it seems it only happens in iOS 10. In my case, if I test it using iOS 9.x no leaks will occur.